# WCF response too long - how to handle in Silverlight?

Tags: wcf, silverlight

My Silverlight 4 client uses a .NET 3.5 WCF service.

The service has the **[SilverlightFaultBehavior]** attribute and exception details from the service are nicely transferred to Silverlight.

However, when the response size is over limit, the client still gets the old **NotFound** exception. Is there a way around this? (I don't want to increase the maximum message size)

Answer (score 0):

I had this message right now. I use a .Net Library for the Domain Models (WCF refers to it) and a Silverlight Library that adds the classes as link from the .net Library. Silverlight project refers to the silverlight library. The issue is:

I'd forgotten add a class from .Net Class Library to Silverlight Class Library. When i fixed it, build and updated the Service reference, it worked perfectly. It may be your ploblem too.
Sorry about my english. I hope that helps.

Comment: I don't think that's it... I don't have a problem transferring data, I have a problem getting the exception detail.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Fiddler?
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Try calling the Web service while runing Fiddler. Sometimes it gives more informative error messages if you inspect the responses with Fiddler.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve my problem of passing this individual error message to the client. (yes, I use fiddler regularly for debugging)